# Field extension over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I am given a subfield $E$ of $\mathbb{C}$ and asked to show that $[E : \mathbb{Q}] \le 10$ when every element of $E$ is a root of a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree $10$.

But I don't think this is true. Say that $E$ contains the square roots of the first $5$ primes. Then when I stack these on top of each other, I have a degree $32$ extension inside $E$. Note that each of them satisfies $x^8(x^2 - p)$, $p$ prime.

Should the question instead say minimal polynomial? Thanks.

Comment: My scenario cannot happen because then the sum of the square roots will be a primitive element for the stack satisfying a minimal polynomial of degree 32 and so cannot satisfy a polynomial of degree 10.

Comment: This is true. It follows from the primitive element theorem.

Comment: Um, @QiaochuYuan, I agree with you, once it‘s known that $E$ is finite over $\Bbb Q$. Don’t we have to mumble some magic words to argue that in fact the extension must be finite?

Comment: I believe he was silently urging me to find and mumble those words myself which I have. Pick an $\alpha_1$ not in $\mathbb{Q}$ and consider $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1)$. If it is not $E$, pick an $\alpha_2$ and consider $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2) = \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ by the primitive element theorem and note that $[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)] \geq 2$. So $[\mathbb{Q}(\beta): \mathbb{Q}] \geq 4$. Proceed this way till the height of some element pushes past the uniform bound $10$. The contradiction gives you finiteness.

Comment: Looks good @SAK !

Comment: @Lubin: finiteness also follows from the primitive element theorem, since an infinite algebraic extension necessarily contains subextensions of arbitrarily large finite degree (as SAK's argument shows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your counterexample isn't valid, and here's why:

One implication of the [primitive element theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem) is that, for any finite extension $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, we have $K = \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ for some $\alpha \in K$.  Also recall that the degree of an algebraic extension $\mathbb{Q}[\beta]$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is equal to the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Now let $E$ be the field we get by adjoining the square roots of the first five primes to $\mathbb{Q}$.  Applying the above facts, we know that $E = \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ for some $\alpha \in E$.  Specifically, $\alpha = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{7} + \sqrt{11}$ works as Spooky mentioned.  Since $[E: \mathbb{Q}] = 32$, it follows that the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ must have degree $32$.

Coincidentally, the primitive element theorem also guarantees the result you are trying to prove!  As mentioned in the comments, however, you will first need to make an argument that $E$ is a *finite* extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ in order to apply the primitive element theorem.

Answer (score 2):

But $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{7} + \sqrt{11}$ doesn't satisfy a non-constant degree $10$ polynomial. The element will have minimal polynomial of degree $32$.

Comment: Another math mystery laid to rest by Spooky.